# issue while receiving correct data from java client

Tags: java, c#, client-server

I have a TCP client-server architecture. Server is written in C# and Client is written in Java.
I want to get MAC address of Client device. Connection between both is working. When I send packet with data **"IPMAC"** it is received and decoded correctly.
But when I send the MAC address to Server, it changes the data in it.

Java code for sending:

```
InetAddress ip;
        try {
            ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);
            byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
            }
            outStream.write(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            System.out.println("Data sent " + sb.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to get MAC address of device or send it to server");
        }
```

C# code for receiving:

```
size = 6;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[6];
        int received = 0;
        ticks = Environment.TickCount;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                if (Environment.TickCount > ticks + timeout)
                    throw new TimeoutException("Timout while receiving!");
                received = received + client.Client.Receive(buffer, received, size - received, SocketFlags.None);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (buffer.Length > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Packet received!", "Wow", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append(String.Format("%02X%s", buffer[i], (i < buffer.Length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
                }
                Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(buffer));
                break;
            }
        }
        while (received < size);
```

I am using **UTF-8** encoding on both side.

**MAC address sent: 00-08-BA-11-00** 
**MAC address received: A1-21-00-00-00**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to make sure you're decoding the bytes as UTF-8 as well

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
```

In java you take bytes representing integers `byte[] mac` and perform a string format on them `String.format("%02X%s"...`. You take this string, turn it into bytes and send it through the socket. The bytes you receive on the C# side represent UTF-8 characters, **not integers**, so don't try to string format them again. Remove the `StringBuilder` on the C# client and just decode the bytes into a utf8 string like above.

Also why did you pick the receive bytes size to be `size = 6;`? What if there are more than 6 bytes of data? The string `"00-08-BA-11-00"` in utf8 is 14 bytes long!

One solution might be to send the size of the data before sending the data. I asked for a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118380/reading-and-writing-messages-from-a-socket) on something similar the other week if you are interested!

Comment: thanks. but i have used 'Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));' but i give me some '??' characters enclosed box.